# Average ticket response time by week with SQL query

Tags: sql, sqlite

In my Spiceworks database there is a table, tickets, with two columns I am concerned with, first_response_secs and created_at.

I have been tasked with finding the average response time of tickets for every week.

So if I run the following query:

```
select AVG(first_response_secs) from (
    select first_response_secs,created_at
    from tickets
    where created_at BETWEEN '2017-03-19' and '2017-03-25'
)
```

I will get back the average first response seconds for that week. But that's as far as my limited SQL gets me. I need 6 months worth of data and I don't want to manually edit the date range and rerun the query 24 times.

I would like to write a query that will return output similar to the following:

```
WEEK                            AVERAGE RESPONSE TIME(secs)
-----------------------------------------------------------
2017-02-26 - 2017-03-04         21447
2017-03-05 - 2017-03-11         20564
2017-03-12 - 2017-03-18         25883
2017-03-19 - 2017-03-25         12244
```

Or something like that, back 6 months.

Comment: Group by the week. See the [documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html).

Comment: I would suggest you create a table where you have a row for each date, add additional information for that date. Then you can you use this table in your join.

Answer (score 0):

Weeks are tricky.  How about:

```
select min(created_at) as weekstart, first_response_secs, created_at
from tickets
group by floor(julianday('2017-03-25) - julianday(created_at)) % 7 = 0
order by weekstart
```

Answer (score 0):

One dirty way is to use `case` to define week boundaries:

```
select week, avg(first_response_secs)
from (
    select case 
        when created_at between '2017-02-26' and '2017-03-04' then '2017-02-26 - 2017-03-04' 
        when created_at between '2017-03-05' and '2017-03-11' then '2017-03-05 - 2017-03-11' 
        when created_at between '2017-03-12' and '2017-03-18' then '2017-03-12 - 2017-03-18' 
        when created_at between '2017-03-19' and '2017-03-25' then '2017-03-19 - 2017-03-25'
        end as week,
    first_response_secs
    from tickets
    ) t 
group by week;
```

#### [Demo](https://sqliteonline.com/#fiddle-58d968508a9d7588ab7125aedcdd8f660ff9b02b8dd5442123)

Note that this method is a general purpose one and can be modified to change the boundaries as you wish.